# Entering Data into a spreadsheet through a UserForm in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am new to VBA in Excel, and I have a basic userform which is to place the data into the sheet. the data from the form is to enter in cell B13 through to G13, then every other entry after should be done on the next row down e.g. B14-G14.

I have this code already however it isnt entering the data into the correct cell and is repeatedly entering it on the same row...

```
     Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lngWriteRow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

If lngWriteRow < 13 Then lngWriteRow = 13

    ws.Range("B" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox1.Value
    ws.Range("C" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox2.Value
    ws.Range("D" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox3.Value
    ws.Range("E" & lngWriteRow) = ComboBox1.Value
    ws.Range("F" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox4.Value
    ws.Range("G" & lngWriteRow) = ComboBox2.Value

End Sub
```

How would i achieve this? (There is already data on the rows below)

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should remove the other question and make an edit here. what is your problem with the solution I gave you? it did what you initially asked for - so, what changed?!

Comment: @Jook, implement something like this `NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` and it should always go to the next row.

Comment: @t.thielemans I think his problem was not as much going to the next row, but starting from row 13, then go to the next row for any further data.

Comment: @Jook, I think he means if he runs that it will fill in the columns for row 13 (or whatever row he starts from), but if he runs it again it will overwrite the current data because the start position is fixed. So the way I see it: he runs this row 13 is filled in, runs it again, row 14 gets filled, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line here is wrong:

```
lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 12) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

Because you are referring to column 12, which you do not alter - hence the row stays the same.

Use this instead

```
lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

*Edit:*

If you want an **initial** offset, to start the data-input @ row 13, use this:

```
lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

if lngWriteRow < 13 then lngWriteRow = 13
```

You cannot use `Offset(12,0)`, because you would use it everytime!

*Edit*

Just to be crystal clear, this here works on an empty sheet, when pasting the code as a worksheet-macro and hitting F5 multiple times. So, unless there is explained, what this does wrong, I consider the question solved.

```
Private Sub Test()

Dim lngWriteRow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

If lngWriteRow < 13 Then lngWriteRow = 13

    ws.Range("B" & lngWriteRow) = "test"
    ws.Range("C" & lngWriteRow) = "test"
    ws.Range("D" & lngWriteRow) = "test"
    ws.Range("E" & lngWriteRow) = "test"
    ws.Range("F" & lngWriteRow) = "test"
    ws.Range("G" & lngWriteRow) = "test"

End Sub
```

*Edit*

After some mailing, here is the solution to this riddle: it was not stated, that there are filled cells beneath those, which shall be entered.

So for col-B it was more like

```
title-row
row13
row..
row..
row63
space
other stuff
```

basically the suggested corrections worked - but they looked for the last filled cell in column B on the whole sheet, which was the problem.

Here is the solution to that:

```
lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(ws.Range("B12:B63")Rows.Count, 2) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

And to give you some explanaition on the way:

You can't use `(Rows.Count,1)` instead of `(Rows.Count,2)`, because you are adding Data in the columns B-G, which is 2-7. You have to use 2-7 because of the way, you are looking for the last row. If you use 1, you're looking for the last value in column A, which does not change, when you are trying to add new data.

You can't use `Offset(12,0)`, because this would create an offset everytime you insert data - so you would end up with rows 12 rows apart.

And finally, you can't use `Rows.Count`, because this is 65536 or so, and you have data beneath the data you are adding. `End(xlUp)` will lookup from too far down, and stop at the last cell of column B, which has data in it - but this won't be B13, unless there is no data in B14-B65536.

Hope this helps to understand the dynamics here.

Comment: +1 for also adding the check to make sure the value isn't lower than 13 ;)

Comment: that doesnt work, it still will only place it in the same cell

Comment: @user1662306 then there has to be something else, I tested this, worked fine.

Comment: i have edited the original question. does the code look correct?

Comment: @user1662306 nope - you are still using `Offset(12,0)` and `(Rows.Count, 1)`!

Comment: it puts the data  off the UserForm into cells B13-G13, however when it is in, and i want to add another form of data, it clearly will overwrite the data in B13-G13. and for the record, when i use `(Rows.Count, 2)` it does nothing, when i use `(Rows.Count, 1)` it finds column "B"

Comment: @user1662306, makes no sense because `rows.count, 1 = colA`, `rows.count, 2 = colB`

Comment: i will send you the spreadsheet if that is what i have to do to prove this? haha