# Why wont this automatically post the next entry to the next row?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have produced this code to sit on a button that belongs to a UserForm...

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lngWriteRow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp) _
.Offset(12, 0).NextRow

    ws.Range("B" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox1.Value
    ws.Range("C" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox2.Value
    ws.Range("D" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox3.Value
    ws.Range("E" & lngWriteRow) = ComboBox1.Value
    ws.Range("F" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox4.Value
    ws.Range("G" & lngWriteRow) = ComboBox2.Value

End Sub
```

It wont automatically move to the next row, and will overwrite the row number 14, when i want it to update 15 when 14 has data in it, then when 15 does, update 16 and so on...

Any ideas?

Comment: row 14 is your first row? cause you're not using a variable most likely!

Comment: the first row that i want the data to be inserted into yes

Comment: Didn't you just ask the same question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472425/entering-data-into-a-spreadsheet-through-a-userform-in-excel/13472612#13472612

Comment: that worked and inserted the data into the sheet, but not where i want it to go and to automatically go to the next row

Comment: i want the data to go in to B13 - G13, then to B14 - G14 and so on

Comment: `lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)` -> again, this is false, because you only add-data to cols, B-G, so it has to be 2-7 ;)

Comment: add a check to find the lastrow and use that variable + 1, you will always have the row below.

Comment: `NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` use `NextRow` as your variable to assign what row to use.

Comment: ah - I think I got where we misunderstand, but I will countinue on your initial question - this there should be removed.

Comment: where would i place that variable?

Comment: @user1662306 look at my edit in your inital question. t.thielemans might not work, becasue he is also using colA, which you seem not to change - therfore its not working eighter. Please don't post CODE as comment! - put it into your INITIAL QUESTION as an edit!

Comment: can you re edit it? i think yours isnt showing...

Comment: it should: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13472612/1370465

Comment: it doesnt work, see other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only placing data in columns B onwards, you should look at those columns, not column A as your code is currently doing. This should fix it:

```
lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(12, 0).Row + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

While John seems to have hit the nail on the head, I think you can further simplify your code like this. See my comment under where `lngWriteRow` is assigned:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lngWriteRow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws

    '-> if you are going to offset 12 rows then add 1 more, just offset to 13 and be done!
    lngWriteRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(13, 0).Row

    .Range("B" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox1.Value
    .Range("C" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox2.Value
    .Range("D" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox3.Value
    .Range("E" & lngWriteRow) = ComboBox1.Value
    .Range("F" & lngWriteRow) = TextBox4.Value
    .Range("G" & lngWriteRow) = ComboBox2.Value

End With

End Sub
```